# Google App Scripts - Ping chat if Google Sheets cell is >1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

After hours of searching and trying I come here once again for your help. I have a google Sheets file which counts certain things on cell A1 using =COUNTA. I want to receive a message on google chat every time A1>1.

I will leave my code down below (it works when you click run it) but I don't know how to trigger it only if cell A1>1.

```
function webhook() {
  const url = "HERE GOES THE URL FROM THE CHATS WEBHOOK";
  const options = {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
      "text": "⚠️ Please verify. Thank you!"
    })
  };
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: There are no triggers that fire when a cell changes it's value due to the action of a formula or another script.

Comment: Good to know that! Are there any workarounds?

Comment: timebased triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there isn't a direct way to "watch" for changes in a cell's formula, but you still have a couple of ways to handle this:

- Use a simple [`onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) trigger. I'm guessing the `COUNTA` value on A1 will change whenever there's a change somewhere else in the Sheet, so either way the trigger should fire and check the value. You can just use [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) on the cell to check. It would look something like this:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your Sheet")
  var countcell = sheet.getRange("A1")

  if (countcell.getValue() > 1){
    webhook() //run your webhook post
  }
}
```

The trigger will run whenever there's a change in the Sheet and just check the value.

- If for some reason the A1 value can change without the Sheet being edited you can instead create an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) time-based trigger to check the value every n minutes. You can create them in the UI by clicking the "Triggers" tab on the left hand side of the page, but you can also create a function to build it programmatically. Like this:

```
function createTrigger(){
  //run this only once to create the trigger
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onEdit")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(5)
  .create();
}
```

In this case you still need to use the `onEdit()` function in my first example but creating the time-based trigger will make it run on its own depending on the time that you set. It can be 1, 5, 10, 15 or 30 minutes. Might want to set it to something sensible to avoid flooding your chat.

##### Sources:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Time-based Trigger Builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)

Comment: Yes, but as I said in my answer, this will still work if the count function changes based on user input somewhere else in the Sheet. If that is the case for OP's sheet then there's no practical difference since the trigger can still read the count value. If that is not the case then he can use the time-based trigger. Perhaps you should have read the answer more closely.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Do you have any idea how I can include the value inside A2 in the text being sent?  So my message would be: "[A2] Please verify. Thank you!". The value in A2 changes from a formula and the value I want is the one the moment the message is posted. Any ideas?

Comment: Glad to see it worked. Within the same `onEdit` function you can just create a new variable with the value of the A2 cell. Something like `var a2cell = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue()`. Then you can just add a parameter to your webhook function like `webhook(cell){...`. Then you can just call `webhook(a2cell)` within the `if` to pass the value to your function and the `cell` variable should have the value that you can add to your message. Let me know if that was clear enough.